# Redis as a cache - timeout and maxclients setting

Tags: caching, redis

If I'm using Redis as a cache, what's the recommended timeout (idle connections) and maxclients (connected clients) setting and how would it affect performance or ability to handle load? When would I encounter any bottlenecks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These parameters have no impact about the throughput you can sustain with a Redis instance.

You just have to make sure the maxclients value is higher than the expected number of connections you will get on Redis.

To get an overview of the bottlenecks you can experience with Redis, i would suggest to start with the following page.

http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: Thanks. How will I know the number of connections I'll get on Redis?

Comment: It is the number of simultaneous connections, so it depends on your application. But I would say at least one per process (or thread if your app in multi-threaded).